# Local project module not found

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why TS cannot find the module in my project but in another project it just works. 
My project : https://github.com/JesusTheHun/react-typescript-boilerplate-big 
The project I'm draining information from is https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-realworld-app .

In my project `ProjectTypes` is declared in `store/types.d.ts` and imported in `store/index.ts`, but TS doesn't find it. In the other project, it is declared the same way in `store/types.d.ts` and also imported in `store/index.ts`. 
It works just fine for one and not for mine.

I used the same versions of TypeScript for both, and afaik after checking several times every config is the same. 
I must be missing something, I can't figure out what it is.

I tried to `--traceResolution`, it says it uses "cache" to resolve the module in the other project, and only search in node_modules for my project.

Here are some samples :

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["src", "typings"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.spec.*"],
  "extends": "./node_modules/react-redux-typescript-scripts/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {

  }
}
```

The extended tsconfig.json

```
// ./node_modules/react-redux-typescript-scripts/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./", // relative paths base
    // "paths": {
    //   "@src/*": ["src/*"], // will enable import aliases -> import { ... } from '@src/components'
    //   //WARNING: Require to add this to your webpack config -> resolve: { alias: { '@src': PATH_TO_SRC } }
    //   "redux": ["typings/redux"], // override library types with your alternative type-definitions in typings folder
    //   "redux-thunk": ["typings/redux-thunk"] // override library types with your alternative type-definitions in typings folder
    // },
    "outDir": "dist/", // target for compiled files
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // no errors with commonjs modules interop
    "esModuleInterop": true, // enable to do "import React ..." instead of "import * as React ..."
    "allowJs": true, // include js files
    "checkJs": false, // typecheck js files
    "declaration": false, // don't emit declarations
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, // include only if using decorators
    "experimentalDecorators": true, // include only if using decorators
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true, // importing transpilation helpers from tslib
    "noEmitHelpers": true, // disable inline transpilation helpers in each file
    "jsx": "preserve", // preserving JSX
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"], // you will need to include polyfills for es2017 manually
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": ["jest"], // which global types to use
    "target": "es5", // "es2015" for ES6+ engines
    "module": "esnext", // "es2015" for tree-shaking
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Module declaration

```js
import { StateType, ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions';

declare module 'ProjectTypes' {
  export type Store = StateType<typeof import('./index').default>;
  export type RootAction = ActionType<typeof import('./actions').default>;
  export type RootState = StateType<ReturnType<typeof import('./reducers').default>>;
}

declare module 'typesafe-actions' {
  interface Types {
    RootAction: ActionType<typeof import('./root-action').default>;
  }
}
```

Import that doesn't work

```js
import { RootAction, RootState, Services } from 'ProjectTypes';
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52449433/1331578 . When You move single export to single file all should work as expected.
If You want to use more complicated types You have to match orginal repo more closely.
So You missing in /services file types.d.ts
if You place inside them

```
declare module 'ProjectTypes' {
export type Services = typeof import('./index').default;
}
```

Services will start to work from ProjectTypes. Same could be done for other types.

Comment: If so, why does in work in the project I mentionned ?

Comment: I updated my answer. So basically You need to add types.d.ts into /services as in original project to make it work like original. This make it work in my clone of your repo.

Comment: Do you know the reason ?

Comment: I guess typeof import('./actions').default is imported correctly, but 
ActionType<typeof import('./actions').default>
is not imported correctly. Only strange thing that is not marked as invalid so maybe it is valid but not usable.

Comment: This looks like strange mix of typescript and javascript mix. If it build one time correctly the next time it will work. So the only problem is to build it correctly at first time. so in Types first enough is to write 'RootAction: RootAction;' then it could be replaced by ActionType<... ' .

Comment: from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36042#issuecomment-576906063  "Suggestions start appearing once you manually imported at least one type from the module in your file."

Comment: I guess it's because first successful import was from /services. Then rest would build just right.